# MSBuild Task, how to remove nested directories?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

As the result of a build task, I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
{BuildOutput}\Database\Customer\Scripts
{BuildOutput}\Database\Customer\obj
{BuildOutput}\Database\Customer\obj\Debug
{BuildOutput}\Database\Logging\Scripts
{BuildOutput}\Database\Logging\obj
{BuildOutput}\Database\Logging\obj\Debug
```

I am trying to write an MSBuild build task that will remove the 'obj' directories and their subdirectories, but leave the rest. Here I've shown `Customer` & `Logging`, but because the script only builds projects that have changed, there could be many others or none at all. This seems to be the tricky bit.

I've tried many different things. In PowerShell, outside of MSBuild, this selects the correct directories:

```
[System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories('$(OutputRoot)\Database', 'obj', ([System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories))
```

But inside of MSBuild:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <UnusedDirs Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories('$(OutputRoot)\Database', 'obj', ([System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)))" />
</ItemGroup>
<Message Text="Cleaning up non required database directories" />
<RemoveDir Directories="@(UnusedDirs)" />
```

Gives this error message:

```
D:\Dev\Application\Package.proj(176,29): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories('$(OutputRoot)\Database', 'obj', ([System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories))". Requested value '([System.IO.Sea
rchOption]::AllDirectories)' was not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).
```

It just doesn't seem to understand the `SearchOption` enum. Is there a way of getting this to work in MSBuild? Or is there another way to delete these directories?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invoke .NET framework functions directory. You can use the `RemoveDir` task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="clobber"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

   <Target Name="clobber">
      <ItemGroup>
        <_ClobberDirectories Include=".\**\obj"/>
      </ItemGroup>
      <RemoveDir Directories="@(_ClobberDirectories)" ContinueOnError="true"/>
   </Target>

</Project>
```

About the `ContinueOnError` your opinion might be different.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that `RemoveDir` [does not support wild cards](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/cfa43dc7-c1a0-4b8b-b712-455e41e13801/wildcard-does-not-always-work), hence the need for all of this silly `Get-Directories` stuff. Would be _soooo_ much simpler if did support wild cards...

Comment: But the "ItemGroup" is expanded to the list of directories, no wild cards left. (You can check replacing RemoveDir with `<Message Text="@(_ClobberDirectories)" Importance="high" />`. So it will delete the "obj" directories it finds in the tree and (by definition) all files/directories beneath them. I personally use it in my projects. So I might understand your question wrong.

Comment: Outputing the `itemGroup` matches is helpful - thanks for that. It seems that `itemGroup` only works with files. If I change the include to `$(OutputRoot)\**` I get all the files, but not directories. If I change it to `$(OutputRoot)\**\obj` I get no matches at all and there are definitely `obj` directories.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the way MSBuild handles enum values as well, but then figured out that this will work:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToRemove Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($(RootDir), '*', System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))" />
</ItemGroup>
```